# Select result of subquery in CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery, common-table-expression

I am using a CTE that has a subquery within it. I am then trying to select from the result of the subquery in the CTE but I am getting an `Invalid Column Name` error.

Query:

```
DECLARE @User AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @User = 'test.user'

WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
    o.db_OrderNo,
    o.db_Deferral
FROM
    tblOrders o
    LEFT JOIN tblUserProfile up on up.db_UserId = o.db_RTS
WHERE
    o.db_Deleted = 0
    AND (select OrderBucketId from Main.udfGetOrderStatusStepInfoByOrderNo(o.db_OrderNo) as Task) IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
    AND up.db_Email LIKE @User + '%'
)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN Task = 1 AND db_Deferral = 0 THEN db_OrderNo
                   END)) as OrderInEvalCount,
   COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN Task = 2 AND db_Deferral = 0 THEN db_OrderNo
                   END)) as OrderInDfcCount,
   COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN Task IN (3, 4) AND (select OrderStepId from Main.udfGetOrderStatusStepInfoByOrderNo(o.db_OrderNo)) NOT IN (37, 39) AND
                             db_Deferral = 0 THEN db_OrderNo
                   END)) as OrderWipCount,
   COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN db_Deferral <> 0 THEN db_OrderNo
                   END)) as OrderInPendedCount
FROM cte;
```

It is not recognizing `Task` as a column. Not really used to doing subqueries so that format could be wrong. Not sure if a temp table could help here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The only things that count as columns in your CTE are the things in its primary select statement; so, `db_OrderNo` and `db_Deferral`.  If you want to do stuff with `Task` outside the CTE, you'll have to include it with those columns.

Comment: This part of the subquery seems to be meaningless!...  AND (select OrderBucketId from Main.udfGetOrderStatusStepInfoByOrderNo(o.db_OrderNo) as Task) IN (1, 2, 3, 4)

Comment: I would suggest to delete that AND clause and then try to run the query and then figure out what that part is supposed to do,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery is in `WHERE` clause.  Columns only come from the `FROM` clause.  You can handle this in several ways.  If you know the subquery does not return duplicates, then move the logic to the `FROM` clause using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT o.db_OrderNo, o.db_Deferral
      FROM tblOrders o LEFT JOIN
           tblUserProfile
           up on up.db_UserId = o.db_RTS CROSS APPLY
           Main.udfGetOrderStatusStepInfoByOrderNo(o.db_OrderNo) t
      WHERE o.db_Deleted = 0 AND
            t.OrderBucketId  IN (1, 2, 3, 4) AND
            up.db_Email LIKE @User + '%'
     )
```